# Typescript path alias in monorepo

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo setup using yarn workspaces that uses Typescript and have the following structure:

```
- node_modules
- packageA
  |- src (typescript)
  |- lib (compiled from /src)
- packageB
  |- src (typescript)
  |- lib (compiled from /src)
```

Package B uses resources from package A. What I want to be able to do is: import `packageA/src` in `packageB/src` and in the compile process of packageB automatically change the path to `packageA/lib` (the compiled version of A).

I tried setting up the path configuration in tsconfig like:

```
{
  paths: {
    "packageA/src/*": [
       "packageA/lib/*"
     ]
  }
}
```

But the nothing changed in the compiled version. Is their anyway I can make that?

Comment: TypeScript only does the resolution. Use something like webpack for transpilation.